# List files in specified directory without subdirectories

Tags: python, excel, subdirectory

Below code goes thru all excel files including files in sub-folders, how can i only go thru files without files in subfolders. thanks

```
dirpath=Path(pl.PureWindowsPath(values['-FIN-']))
for path in dirpath.rglob("*.xls*"):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `glob` method instead of `rglob` also we gonna use `is_file()` method to checks if the path is a file and not a directory.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

dirpath = Path(values['-FIN-'])
for path in dirpath.glob("*.xls*"):
    if path.is_file():
        print(path)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, i took your advice and used glob instead and it only listed files in current directory and non from sub direcotries...thanks alot